# Summarize multiple variables grouped by names of states

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to R. Idea is to summarize a bunch of variables grouped by states/counties. I want the results in a neat table. Column headings should be states/counties, summary of all variables per state/county.

```
df <- tbl_df(nfhs2)

nfhs.sum <- df %>%
    group_by(ut) %>%
    select(foos>6, fmpop<15,totsexratio, atbirthsexratio, regbirth, regdeath, popelec,popwat,popsan, hhcleanfuel, hhsalt, hhinsured,child.pprimary) %>% # select variables to summarise#
    summarize_each(funs(min = min, 
                      q25 = quantile(., 0.25), 
                      median = median, 
                      q75 = quantile(., 0.75), 
                      max = max,
                      mean = mean, 
                      sd = sd), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Data sample:

```
 structure(list(dist = c("Nicobars", "North & Middle Andaman "
    ), ut = c("Andaman & Nicobar Islands", "Andaman & Nicobar Islands"
    ), hh = c(882, 874), fem = c(764, 789), male = c(125, 108), `foos>6` = c(78, 
    82.7), `fmpop<15` = c(23, 19.8), totsexratio = c(973, 950), atbirthsexratio = c("927 ", 
    "844 "), regbirth = c(98, 100), regdeath = c("83.2 ", "(92.6)"
    ), popelec = c(97.9, 93.2), popwat = c(98.8, 92.2), popsan = c(83.5, 
    86.4), hhcleanfuel = c(56.9, 61.3), hhsalt = c(99.4, 99.9), hhinsured = c(2.7, 
    2.1), child.pprimary = c("(29.5)", "(30.1)"), f.literate = c(87.5, 
    84), `fyrsofschooling>10` = c(53.5, 41), `marriage<18` = c("11.4 ", 
    "15.4 "), thirdorder = c("0.0 ", "1.5 "), youngmothers = c("1.8 ", 
    "3.8 "), periodhygiene = c(100, 100), familyplanning1 = c(65.3, 
    84.1), familyplanning2 = c(57.2, 73.1), familyplanning3 = c(46.4, 
    48.3), familyplanning4 = c(0, 0.6), familyplanning5 = c(2.7, 
    6.4), familyplanning6 = c(2, 7.8), familyplanning7 = c(4.9, 9.3
    ), familyplanning8 = c(1.2, 0), nofamilyplanning = c(9.5, 5.8
    ), nochildspacing = c(3.3, 1.3), fp.awareness = c(40.4, 23.2), 
        fp.sideeffects = c("49.4 ", "83.2 "), ant.chk = c("62.8 ", 
        "74.5 "), `ant.chk=4` = c("71.7 ", "79.2 "), no.tetanus = c("78.0 ", 
        "91.1 "), `iron.folic>100` = c("72.6 ", "83.7 "), `iron.folic>180` = c("43.9 ", 
        "24.1 "), yes.mcp = c("97.9 ", "99.2 "), yes.postntl = c("85.1 ", 
        "92.5 "), personalexp4delivery = c("2278 ", "1904 "), `ccheckup<24hrs` = c("*", 
        "*"), child.postntl = c("92.5 ", "94.3 "), inst.birth = c(97.8, 
        97.7), govt.inst.birth = c(96.7, 95), homebirth = c(0.8, 
        0.7), profbirth = c(98.6, 98.3), csection.birth = c(11.5, 
        12.9), pvt.inst.birth = c("*", "*"), csection.birth.govt = c("10.7 ", 
        "11.4 "), mixed.vaccine.recall = c("(64.2)", "*"), vaccine.card.recall = c("(94.1)", 
        "*"), tb.vaccine = c("(80.4)", "*"), polio.vaccine = c("(69.1)", 
        "*"), dpt.vaccine = c("(71.9)", "*"), measle.vaccine1 = c("(67.3)", 
        "*"), measle.vaccine2 = c("(20.7)", "*"), rotavirus.vaccine = c("(3.1)", 
        "*"), HPB.vaccine = c("(68.6)", "*"), vitAdose = c("94.9 ", 
        "(89.6)"), govt.vaccine = c("(100.0)", "*"), pvt.vaccine = c("(0.0)", 
        "*"), got.loosemotions = c(5.7, 4.5), ORS = c("*", "*"), 
        zinc = c("*", "*"), hospice.loosemotions = c("*", "*"), ari = c(1.8, 
        7), hospice.ari = c("(85.7)", "*"), `breastfed<1hr` = c("55.4 ", 
        "27.3 "), exclusive.breastfed = c("*", "*"), supple.breastfed = c("*", 
        "*"), adequate.breastfed = c("(19.4)", "(6.5)"), adequate.nonbreastfed = c("*", 
        "*"), adequate.diet = c("(18.7)", "(5.9)"), chld.stunted = c("21.6 ", 
        "27.0 "), chld.wasted = c("15.7 ", "27.0 "), chld.severely.wasted = c("7.8 ", 
        "8.3 "), chld.uweight = c("24.6 ", "42.8 "), chd.oweight = c("1.5 ", 
        "0.8 "), lowBMI = c(8.2, 8.6), obese = c(39.1, 35.9), high.wth = c(62.5, 
        79.3), chd.anaemia = c("37.7 ", "30.4 "), female.anaemia = c(38.4, 
        62.5), preg.anaemia = c("*", "*"), totfem.anaemia = c(38.3, 
        62.1), `1519.anaemia` = c("48.0 ", "47.8 "), female.sugar.high = c(7.4, 
        7.2), female.sugar.vhigh = c(3.9, 6.4), totfemale.sugar = c(13.1, 
        16.7), male.sugar.high = c(9.6, 9.1), male.sugar.vhigh = c(4.4, 
        6.9), totmale.sugar = c(15.4, 18.3), female.bp.mild = c(23.2, 
        18.4), female.bp.elev = c(8.5, 4), totfemale.bp = c(35.4, 
        27.4), male.bp.mild = c(32.9, 22.6), male.bp.elev = c(11.1, 
        6), totmale.bp = c(47, 32.2), cervical.screen = c(13.4, 1.7
        ), breast.exam = c(13.2, 0.3), oral.exam = c(5.4, 15.8), 
        female.tobacco.use = c(63.5, 46.8), male.tobacco.use = c(76.8, 
        70.5), female.alcohol.use = c(29.6, 5.1), male.alcohol.use = c(64.5, 
        45.3)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you sure `select(foos>6, fmpop<15, ...)` doesn't get any errors?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data, just that we're able to give you a reproducible example? For this use `dput(head(your_data, 10))` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: I get this error Adding missing grouping variables: `"ut"`
Error in `as_indices_impl()`:
! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
✖ Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to swap the order of the `select` statement and the group_by statement in your pipe. Second, a `filter` statement is needed to cull the rows using the criteria you identify in the first two arguments of the `select` statement. If you want to create a publication-ready table, you can use the `knitr` package and the `kable` function.
In summary, the code should take this form:
`df%<>% select()%<>% filter()%<>% group_by()%<>% summarize`

Comment: I think the first two arguments are in fact variables named "foos>6" and "fmpop<15".

Comment: It's wrong to use `%<>%` to connect each verb. I think you confuse `%<>%` and `%>%`. In addition, your post is just a comment or suggestion, not an answer.